SQL query giving error msg not enough values
-- table script
CREATE TABLE employees
( 
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, 
    FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(20),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    SALARY NUMBER(8,2),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE emp_seq  --Sequence creation
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     NOCACHE;

Question: when I tried to run this insert query, I get an error "not enough values":
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, last_name, hiredate)
VALUES ((SELECT emp_seq.nextval, 'Smith', SYSDATE FROM dual));

Can someone explain why?
I tried running nested select statement individually, getting desired result, but when tried both queries together I'm getting that error.

The syntax diagrams in the documentation show the two forms of single-table insert, with a values clause or a subquery - you're mixing them up. (You can use a subquery as a column expression within a values clause but that's not what you're trying to do.)

Simply do INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2) select exp1, exp2 FROM ....

Sample table and sequence:
SQL> CREATE TABLE employees(
  2    employee_id   NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, ---table script
  3    first_name    VARCHAR2(20),
  4    last_name     VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
  5    salary        NUMBER(8,2),
  6    hiredate      DATE,
  7    department_id NUMBER(4));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE emp_seq  --Sequence creation
  2    START WITH 1
  3    INCREMENT BY 1
  4    NOCACHE;

Sequence created.

Indeed, your insert won't work because ...
SQL> INSERT INTO employees
  2    (employee_id, last_name, hiredate)
  3     VALUES ( (SELECT emp_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Smith', sysdate FROM dual) );
   VALUES ( (SELECT emp_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Smith', sysdate FROM dual) )
             ----------------------------------------------------
             ... all of this is considered to be employee_id
   *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00947: not enough values

But, if you put it this way:
SQL> INSERT INTO employees
  2    (employee_id, last_name, hiredate)
  3    (SELECT emp_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Smith', sysdate FROM dual);

1 row created.

Or this:
SQL>  INSERT INTO employees
  2    (employee_id, last_name, hiredate)
  3     VALUES ( emp_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Jones', sysdate );

1 row created.

Then it works.
SQL> SELECT * FROM employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                     SALARY HIREDATE            DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ---------- ------------------- -------------
          1                      Smith                                27.10.2024 10:03:44
          2                      Jones                                27.10.2024 10:03:57

SQL>


On the other hand, if your database version allows it (I guess/hope you aren't on 11g or lower?), you could have used identity column and let Oracle handle IDs:
SQL> DROP TABLE employees;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE employees(
  2    employee_id   NUMBER(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, ---table script
  3    first_name    VARCHAR2(20),
  4    last_name     VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
  5    salary        NUMBER(8,2),
  6    hiredate      DATE,
  7    department_id NUMBER(4));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO employees
  2    (last_name, hiredate)
  3     VALUES ('Smith', sysdate );

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                     SALARY HIREDATE            DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ---------- ------------------- -------------
          1                      Smith                                27.10.2024 10:09:18

SQL>

